# Laurent Series, region of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to find the laurent series for 
$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 - (1+i)z +i}
$$ in powers of $z-1$ and find the region of convergence. I am not quite sure how to do this. 
I know that 
$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-i) }
$$
but I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I have not, I am unsure of how to find the series representation for this

Comment: Use partial fractions decompositions of $f(z)$.

Comment: So, you end up getting ((z-1) + 1) /( z(z-1) - i(z-1) ) 

= ( z-1 / z(z-1) - i(z-1) ) +      1/ (z(z-1) - i(z-1) )

Comment: Unless I made a mistake, I got $\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{i}{i+1}\frac{1}{z-1}$ dont distribute the constants.

Comment: That is correct I just redid it

Comment: Now you should be able to find the Laurent series representation of $f(z)$ and use ratio test to determine the ROC, correct?

Comment: ok, thanks can I compute it and check back with you if it is correct?

Comment: Of course. added char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rewrite $f$:
$$
f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2 - (1+i)z +i} =  \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-i)} = \left(\frac{A}{z-1} + \frac{B}{z-i}\right) = \frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{i}{z-i}\right).
$$
Since you want the expansion around $1$, let's write everything in terms of $(z-1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &=\frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{i}{(z-1)+(1-i)}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that $f$ has two singularities, one at $1$ and the other at $i$, so if you want the Laurent expansion around $1$ it has to be done for two different cases: $|z-1|<\sqrt{2}$ and $|z-1|>\sqrt{2}$. Then, for $|z-1|<\sqrt{2}$ we have that $|z-1|<|1-i|$, so:
$$
\begin{align}
f(z) & = \frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{i}{1-i}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{z-1}{1-i}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{i}{1-i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{z-1}{1-i}\right)^k\right).
\end{align}
$$
Analogously if $|z-1|>|1-i|=\sqrt{2}$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(z) & = \frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{i}{z-1}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1-i}{z-1}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{1-i}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{i}{z-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac{1-i}{z-1}\right)^k\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: hehe, glad to help!